# Convert Asp.Net to MVC and resuse Asp.net Partial Views in MVC Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create an Hybrid App with open community forums (*yetanotherforum*) which is written in ASP.Net as the base and all my extensions would be written in MVC.

I added all the references & applied tweaks to `web.config` and `global.asax` and now I can run both .aspx and mvc pages fine.

But when I tried to embed UserControls defined in Asp.net into MVC razor pages by using the following line of code :

```
@Html.Partial("~/pages/login.ascx")
```

And it is throwing an Error as follows:

```
The view at '~/pages/login.ascx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
```

Is it possible to render .net web controls in the MVC Pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a post with demo code for this [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/dudu/archive/2012/05/03/asp_net_mvc_ascx.html), but it is written in chinese language. may be you can read via google translating service. You can also download the code at the end of the post:

the link to the demo code is: [here](http://files.cnblogs.com/dudu/CNBlogsDemoMvcAscx.rar)